# cp: cannot create directory '/home/rexxi/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins': No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, firefox, copy, cp

I tried to move files from downloads dir

```
cp -r ~/Downloads/flash_player_npapi_linux.x86_64 ~/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins
```

And I got a error message

```
cp: cannot create directory '/home/rexxi/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins': No such file or directory
```

But if I open another terminal and write

```
$ /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins
bash: /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins: Is a directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Nb: I am a Windows user trying to switch to Linux.

Answer (score 3):

```
~/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins
```

and

```
/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins
```

are different paths.

The first one is relative and is actually

```
/home/$USER/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins
```

The second is absolute.

The correct command seems to be

```
sudo cp -r ~/Downloads/flash_player_npapi_linux.x86_64 /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins
```

But it's not clear for me what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

Rather using command lines, You can open file manager with root access in order to alter or make changes in directories like usr, share et.c...

Nautilus is default filemanager in Ubuntu 18.04.

so use sudo nautilus, type password, BANG!.

so I`m not sure if same method work for some other FM like dolphin, spaceFM e.t.c..